# How to do a || "b" in rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

we validate objects with and without namespaces and I always want to print what the current namespace is ... but fallback to "" or some other default value when no namespace is set.

using the naive `input.review.object.metadata.namespace` directly fails the rule, so I resorted to

```
namespace := [input.review.object.metadata.namespace | ""]
```

which prints an array, kinda ugly but it works ... is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a nice operator for it, although there is discussion underway to add one.

Generally the pattern is to use a helper rule/function that has the accessor and a negative one with a default. For example:

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/RhZVyJjqOJ
Uses..

```
# If the namespace exists, use it
input_namespace = ns {
    ns := input.review.object.metadata.namespace
}

# or if it doesn't, use the string defined here
input_namespace = "whatever-default-value-i-want" {
    not input.review.object.metadata.namespace
}
```

This same kind of pattern can be seen in the wild too, for example in the Gatekeeper library: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/blob/master/library/general/requiredlabels/src.rego#L3-L10